# Enterprise Mobile-first multi-team-product organization

Tags: scrum, team-management, enterprise

I am the mobile product owner (PO) at a firm with a dozen or so scrum teams each managing their own web products.  My team builds mobile versions of the above web products.  I work with each product owner to bring features of their web apps to our mobile platform picking and choosing features that make the most sense on mobile.  We build native iOS and Android apps sharing the same backend API's each products web team created.

My firm's long-term goal is to strive for mobile-first products and features that will eventually make their way into each web product.  I am tasked with looking across all of the teams to determine if it still makes sense to have a single mobile scrum team in lieu of each web team building both mobile and web versions of their products.  Bringing dedicated iOS and android developers to each web scrum team.  That way each team controls their product from mobile to web.  Their domain knowledge stays within the team vs the mobile team having to understand and keep up with each team's direction, quirks, priorities etc.

I feel it would be very difficult for each web team to manage the diversity of mobile challenges with consistent results.  What are other firms doing?  When a team owns a product does that team typically build mobile & web? or leave mobile (as we do) to a dedicated mobile team.  Thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you are trying to change - creating Mobile Apps requires a different skill set from creating Web Apps. As long as all teams understand how to interface with the back-end, there's not much to be gained by insisting the Mobile Teams to also create the Web version.

Answer (score 1):

Lately the cases that I see are usually the other way around - building web (and mobile web) to catch up to the mobile apps :)

But to answer your question - it is possible to have a scrum team of mobile + web + backend working within a certain domain with the PO responsible for that domain - be it identity management, payments, online chat, whatever. This would mean that tackling the mobile platform challenges across the scrum teams (code guidelines, builds, releases) need to be agreed upon beforehand. It's also a good idea for the mobile guys to have iOS/Android technical check-in meetings every now and again. Not part of Scrum events really, but much better than having wild arguments on Slack every day :)